# Column <column name> does not belong to table <table name>

Tags: c#, sql, iis, ado.net, dataset

I have a method working with dataset,

```
 var EmpNameList = new List<string>();
 var EmpDS = GetEmployeeList();
 foreach (DataRow EmpDR in EmpDS.Tables[0].Rows)
 {
     EmpNameList.Add(EmpDR["EmpName"].ToString()); // Error on this line
 }
```

exception Details:

> Column 'EmpName' does not belong to table 'EmpDetailTbl'
>          at System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName)
>          at System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(String columnName)
>          at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)

at times we also get the following exception for the same method

> Cannot find table 0 at System.Data.DataTableCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)

All the above exception are not reproduced consistently and it is intermittent.

The GetEmployeeList definition looks as below

```
  public DataSet GetEmployeeList()
  {
    var  Connectionstring = "MyConnectionString";
    var query = "Select EmpName, EmpId, HireDate from EmpDetail"; 
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(Connectionstring))
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
    {
      adapter.Fill(ds,"EmpDetailTbl");
      return ds;
    }
 }
```

I have tried with SQL Server using the SqlConnection class also.

This seems to be wierd huh???

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting results for the EmpDS data set?..

Comment: @PEO we getting the value returned in EmpDS.

Comment: @Grant This is a replica of the actual code, I have corrected the Rows

Comment: I think you are not getting any result for that data set that's the why it calming "Cannot find table 0". so check your db connection and table name again. cheers

Comment: When the error occurs, what the debugging show you about the relevant variables, such as EmpDS and EmpDR?

Comment: @PEO, if he wasn't getting any rows, the error would not occur.  He is in a foreach loop.

Comment: @PEO we have the dataset returned with values

Comment: Yes you guys correct so can you post the screen shot what you getting for the data set.

Comment: @PEO, the dataset is returning with schema when no records are selected, This is a replica of the code in production

Comment: put your table name instant of array number

Answer (score 3):

If you are filling other DataTables in the DataSet then "EmpDetailTbl" may not be the first one every time (0). Refer to the DataTable by name:

```
foreach (DataRow EmpDR in EmpDS.Tables["EmpDetailTbl"].Rows) {
```

Comment: yes you are correct. this is good example for bad practice don't use array number to fetch the table data always use table name. good catch andy G

Comment: @Andy For the reading the value in data row we have used the name (like EmpDR["EmpName"]) we still have this issue saying the column name could not be found in the table???

Comment: As @Jack B indicates, you should check whether your query succeeded and returned some rows. Check `EmpDS.Tables["EmpDetailTbl"].Rows.Count`.

Comment: @AndyG Even if my query is not returning the result and it executes successfully it should return the schema of the table

Comment: You need to debug your code to find out what the problem is. You can't make assumptions as this will just make it harder to discover what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b211hz(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b211hz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Check out the remarks - if the actual query string you're using returns no rows, no tables are added to the dataset. Also note that the strings used are case sensitive.